# show for any Languages $L_1$ and $L_2$ exists a Language $L$ with $L_1 \leq_{log} L$ and $L_2 \leq_{log} L$

Tags: reductions

This is an old exam question, but I never found a solution or somebody who could explain it to me. Here is the problem statement:

Let $\Sigma$ be an alphabet with |$\Sigma$| $\geq 2$.
Show that for any Languages $L_1 \subseteq \Sigma^*$ and $L_2 \subseteq \Sigma^*$ there is a Language $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ and the following holds true:
$L_1 \leq_{log} L$ and $L_2 \leq_{log} L$.

So $L_1$ and $L_2$ are both logspace reducible to $L$

This question gives just 5 out of 60 points for the correct answer, so I assume it shouldn't be too hard to solve. But I don't have any idea on how to approach this problem...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just take $L = \{ 0x \mid x \in L_1 \} \cup \{ 1y \mid y \in L_2\}$.